# How to successfully cross a river without using money

Tags: the-oregon-trail

The title sums it up. I have tried fording 4 foot deep rivers, thinking my wagon and oxen would be tall enough not to drown.

I have never forded successfully. My party members always drown or I always lose items.

Caulking seems to be more successful though. Every so often I cross the river without losing people or items.

It seems like the only way to cross a river without losing anything is to pay for a ferry or trade with an Indian to guide you, so I was wondering if there is there a way to successfully cross rivers without paying or trading?

I'm playing the 1990 version. It can be played [here](https://archive.org/details/msdos_Oregon_Trail_The_1990).

Comment: "It can be played here."   Missing a link? :)

Comment: woops haha, will fix

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fording rivers deeper than 3 feet deep is not recommended and has a high chance to go wrong.

Caulking your wagon when rivers are over 3 feet is recommended.

There is still a chance that something can go wrong when doing this, but this strategy has the highest chance of success.

[Here is a guide](http://www.gamefaqs.com/pc/577345-the-oregon-trail/faqs/30964)

Comment: Thanks, but this guide is for the 1993 version of the game, but the rest of your answer seems correct so i'm accepting it.

Answer (score 3):

**Success Chances**

Fording Rivers:

```
less than 3 ft; 80% chance 
greater than 3 ft; 40% chance
```

Caulking Wagon and Floating:

```
less than 5 ft; 85% chance
greater than 5 ft; 25% chance
```

Taking A Ferry: `80% chance`

Hiring an Indian (Shoshoni): `90% chance`

Tip: Unless you have less than $10, DO NOT take the Columbia River route. It is nearly impossible. Take the Barlow Toll, which usually costs around $10.

Comment: This looks to be a well written answer but it seems to be missing the final sentence.

Comment: @Virusbomb It was a formatting issue, which is fixed in my suggested edit.

Comment: Unless the IBM version of the game speed is noticably different from the Apple II version, I'm inclined to disagree regarding the Columbia River route... it's another mini game and saves time IIRC, and not so nearly impossible as J. Kane implies.  It would have been nice to practice to get a slight feel for the perspecitve vs hit boxes side, but after a couple of times, I don't think I ever hit anything.